# C# Check if string is in a value format

Tags: c#, parsing, string-formatting, cultureinfo

I'm wondering if there's simple way to check if a string is in a value format of any kind.  Meaning the number one-thousand could be represented in any of the following ways:

- 1000
- 1000.00
- 1,000
- 1,000.00
- $1,000.00

I've tried `double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out n)` but that isn't working for items with the currency symbol out in front.  So I tried `double.TryParse(value NumberStyles.Any | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out n)` but that is also not working.

Basically I'd like to check if a value can be considered a number value at all.

Comment: The invariant culture does not use `$` as its currency symbol.  You could try two TryParse calls in succession: one for the current culture, and a fallback for the invariant culture.  Include `AllowCurrencySymbol` on both.  The order of the calls would depend on what culture you most expect to have been used when formatting the value.

Comment: Well it depends on your definition, but you can easily strip out all non-numeric characters and the see if there are any characters left. Something like `var isNumber = (new string("$1,234".Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray()).Length > 0);`

Comment: @MikeStrobel What does Invariant Culture use as it's currency symbol and how does CurrentCulture work exactly?

Comment: @Joe CurrentCulture uses the locale of the host system by default, though it can be overridden (and set on a per-thread basis).  It’s also the format that is used by default when formatting values.  InvariantCulture uses `¤` as its currency symbol.

Comment: Ok so I probably don't want to use invariant then.  Thanks.  Can you add your reply as an answer please @MikeStrobel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invariant culture does not use `$` as its currency symbol; it uses `¤`.

Picking the correct culture for parsing is tricky.  Obviously, it is best to use the same culture that was used to format the value to begin with.  If you *know* which culture was used, you’re lucky :).

By default, unless a specific culture is specified, `CurrentCulture` will be used.  The current culture can be overridden and set on a per-thread basis, but it defaults to the locale settings of the host operating system.  In the absence of other information, `CurrentCulture` is a reasonable first guess.

I would suggest you `||` together at least two `TryParse` calls: one for `CurrentCulture` (or your best guess as to the culture of origin), and a fallback using `InvariantCulture`.  Include `AllowCurrencySymbol` on both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions

https://regexone.com/references/csharp

you can use below code to accept your cases

- 1000
- 1000.00
- 1,000
- 1,000.00
- $1,000.00

  ```
  string pattern = @"^\$?(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*(\.0{2})?)|(\d+(\.0{2})?)$";
  Match result = Regex.Match("$100,000.00", pattern);
  if (result.Success) 
    // your input is in format
  ```